# How can I set up a Stream for a subcollection in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have a Firestore database with the following structure:

usersCollection => user1 => productsHeldCollection => product1, product2, ...

I can set up a Stream for the `userCollection`, but am struggling to set one up for the `productsHeldCollection` which is a subcollection for each user. This is what I have tried.

First I created a reference for the subcollection:

```
final CollectionReference productsHeldCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document().collection('productsHeld');
```

But I am not sure what to pass into the `document()` as I want it to be whatever the current user id is.

I then did the following:

```
List<ProductHeld> _productsHeldListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return ProductHeld(
        productName: doc.data['Product Name'],
        purchaseDate: doc.data['Purchase Date'],
        expiryDate: doc.data['Expiry Date'], // these are fields within the subcollection
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

```
// Stream of products
Stream<List<ProductHeld>> get products {
  return productsHeldCollection.snapshots().map(_productsHeldListFromSnapshot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [names of documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections) within a collection are unique. You can provide your own keys, such as user IDs, or you can let Cloud Firestore create random IDs for you automatically.

The parameter you pass into the document() is the name of the document.

Google public documentation provides more details on how to design your [hierarchical data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data) to work in Cloud Firestore.